# Carriage return via Bash awk

Tags: bash, awk, carriage-return

Another awkward problem

I needed the following code to not add a carriage return at the end of each line.

```
 awk -v coord_file="$txt_1"  '  
 NR <= '$region1' {print $0}
 NR > '$region1' && NR <= '$region2'{$6 = "" ; $7 = "" ; print $0}
 NR > '$region2' {print coord_file} 
 {CONVFMT="%.10f"} ' input.sh > tmp
```

I found I needed to post process my file to remove carriage returns.
All this is done in nested loops hence

```
 IN=tmp
 OUT=output"$[$i]$[$j]".sh
 cat  $IN | tr -d '\r' > $OUT
 rm $IN
```

Comment: That's about as confusing an attempt at an awk script as I've seen. You know how to use awk to read one file (`input.sh`) but not another (`Region_1.txt`). You know to set awk variables from shell variables in some places (`txt_1`) but then you don't for others (`region_1`), you're setting `CONVFMT` for every line of input instead of once and doing it after each line is read, you're testing a condition and it's opposite, etc. Post some sample contents of `input.sh` and what you want the output to be given those 2 input files to help us understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: Thank you Ed, I managed to sort it out.

Comment: Did you find that the carriage return came from the input file and was not added by awk?

Comment: No I suspected that to be the case initially. Found no evidence. I had to nest my cat | tr function to solve it

Answer (score 1):

print adds a newline in awk.
You can repress this by setting ORS (the Output Record Separator) to something else. Or you can use printf instead of print.